# How can I access the data inside dynamically created table rows on the server side?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, angularjs

Just a little background: I am creating an ASP.NET MVC web application.

In my main page I created several table rows using AngularJS, and while I can access them on the client side, my ultimate goal is to process the data on the server side using vb.net. A nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Here is my AngularJS controller used to dynamically add rows to my html table.

```
function TableController($scope){

    $scope.requests = [];

    $scope.addCertificate = function () {
        var certificate = {
            emailAddress: $scope.emailAddress,
            certificateType: $scope.certificateType,
            searchType: $scope.searchType,
            submittedNumbers: $scope.submittedNumbers,
        };

        $scope.requests.push(certificate);
    };

    $scope.removeCertificate = function (index) {
        $scope.requests.splice(index, 1);
    };
}
```

Comment: I don't know about ASP, however if you pass multiple values with the same name, there should be some standard conversion to an array. You can compare items with the same index to know which ones are related to which. The other option is to send the full JSON in the request body and then parse it server side.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the input fields, select boxes, textareas, etc. in the dynamic tables have names associated with them.

You then have two options:

1. Use the same name for the input in each row.  For example, if you have a table with five rows, and each row has an input to hold last name, then those five inputs would be named "LastName".  You're post function could then have the parameter LastName, which would be a comma-delimited string of your values:

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult YourPostFunction(string LastName)
   {
       // split LastName on "," to convert to an array or List and then process.
   }
   ```
2. Index the name of the inputs like you would an array.  For example, if you have a table with five rows, and each row has an input to hold last name, then those five inputs would be named LastName[0], LastName[1], LastName[2], LastName[3], and LastName[4].  You should then be able to access those fields via a MVC action like this:

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult YourPostFunction(List<string> LastName)
   {

   }
   ```

In either case, your MVC action would not need to know the number of LastName fields that were posted to you.  You would have a comma-delimited string or a List you could then iterate through and process accordingly.

More details (and code, if possible) would be needed to provided a more detailed answer.

Comment: This is assuming, of course, you are doing a regular post instead of sending JSON.  If packaging up the form as JSON, you'd parse through the inputs by name based on whatever naming convention you come up with.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning all these keywords. I'm new to web development, so I truly do not know what most of them mean, yet..


I edited in my angularJS script that I use to dynamically add a new row to my html table. As an aside question, why can't I view these controls in my page source?